# Class of well-founded set being a subclass WF $\subset$ M

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to show (Kunen Cha III Ex 3) let M be any class
$$\forall x(x\subset M\rightarrow x\in M)$$
then $WF\subset M$.

I understand that I need to show that $\forall x\in WF\rightarrow x\in M$. However, I don't see what exactly I need to show to prove $x$ is an element of M.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Show, by induction on $\alpha,$ that for each ordinal $\alpha,$ $V_\alpha\subseteq M.$

Comment: Do you mind elaborate the definition of $V_\alpha$?

Comment: @al2000 Kunen’s notation for it is $R(\alpha).$

Comment: @al2000 You could also phrase the proof as an induction on the rank of $x$, but that's very similar.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm still a bit unclear on one thing. If I showed $R(\alpha)\subset M$ then certainly I showed $\forall x\in WF$, $x\in M$. However, I guess my confusion is how can I tie my induction to the definition of M. I.e. let's just say for the induction case, I'm not sure how should I go from $R(\alpha)$ to $R(\alpha + 1)$

Comment: @al2000 You need to show that if $R(\alpha)\subseteq M$ then $R(\alpha+1)\subseteq M.$ To show $R(\alpha+1)\subseteq M,$ you could show that if $x\in R(\alpha+1),$ then $x\in M.$ By definition, $x\in R(\alpha+1)$ means the same thing as $x\subseteq R(\alpha).$ Does that help?